# Move index.html from dir into root dir (vite)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vite

How can I move `index.html` from `src/pages/index/index.html` to `dist/index.html` and `src/pages/donate/index.html` to `dist/pages/donate/index.html` at a build vite project?

My vite.config.js

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

const root = resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

export default defineConfig({
  root,
  build: {
    outDir,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(root, 'pages/index/index.html'),
        donate: resolve(root, 'pages/donate/index.html')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the [rollup options](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-rollupoptions) in your vite config file.

Something like this should get you going in the right direction:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import path from "path";

export default {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    build: {
        outDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                index: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/pages/index/index.html"),
                donate: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/pages/donate/donate.html"),
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: This is not for my build structure.

I have src/pages/index/index.html and src/pages/donate/donate.html. When i build a project, i want to my src/pages/index/index.html move to dist/index.html and src/pages/donate/donate.html move to dist/donate.html. I don't have the knowledge to do this.

Comment: @wowblvck I'm looking to do what you wanted to do in the comment above -- have you found a good solution?

Comment: @thdoan yes, this is good solution for me

Comment: @thdoan what is the solution? I don't see it. this answer isn't working

Comment: @NicholasBiantoro I think wowblvck found the solution, not me.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Vite will always replicate your file input structure in the `dist` folder, and this cannot be changed.  I've had success with using `vite-plugin-handlebars` to inject my source files into other pages that I can then use to get the output structure that I want.

Comment: If these options aren't sufficient, you can always customize the build script in your `package.json` to move, copy, or delete additional files in the `dist` directory. If you need to do more than a couple of things, it might be worth looking into moving your build script into another module or function.

Comment: @thdoan sorry for such a long silence, I'm sure you already found a solution, but just in case I've attached the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

const root = resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/somefolder',
  root,
  build: {
    outDir,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(root, 'index.html'),
        donate: resolve(root, 'pages/donate/index.html')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Now I get this output format:

/somefolder/index.html

/somefolder/pages/donate/index.html